# how do i make only 1 role can do the command.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been making a discord bot with python and I'm trying to make it so only 1 role can do the command I've searched everywhere and I've tried to do it but I always get an error this is the code i would like to apply it to:

> 

```
if message.content.startswith('$leadershipcmds2'):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="hello", description="my commands", color=0x71368a)
    embedVar.add_field(name="commands", value="$training30 ( post a training in 30 mins)", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="commands", value="$training1 ( post a training in 1 hour)", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="commands", value="$activityp (pings everyone to get in radios and be more active)", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="commands", value="$acceptt (if someone requests a training just do $acceptt to post a training) ", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="commands", value="$near (when theres 5 minutes until the training starts)", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="commands", value="and more coming soon!!)", inline=False)
    await message.author.send(embed=embedVar) 
    emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can paste the error message here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to get the role first ofc

You can this by:

```py
@commands.has_role('Role name here')
```

Comment: is that all i need? and where would that go?

Comment: right under @client.command()